# Почему не правильно отображается размер items в collectionview когда меняю с портретного на альбомный вид?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3, xcode7, xcode6.3

[image: Портретный вид]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таббар, который выполнен в виде `collectionview` с 4 items. Размер элементов определяется:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.width/4, height: frame.height)
}
```

Но когда я меняю вид, они меняются в размере, т.е. насколько я понимаю не пересчитывается размер.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуй [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

Comment: А куда это вставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует закрепить высоту collectionView в Storyboard с помощью constraint и добавить метод willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let frame = self.collectionView.frame
    return CGSize(width: frame.width/4, height: frame.height)
}

override func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval) {
    super.willRotate(to: toInterfaceOrientation, duration: duration)

    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

или метод viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator), т.к. willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval) устарел:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```